# I was converting my CSV file to JSON using pandas but, I get the error from Jupyter TypeError: to_json() got an unexpected keyword argument 'indent'

Tags: python, json, pandas, csv, jupyter

That's how I was converting.

```
    json_output = r"/home/umar/Desktop/csv/customer.json"
output = customer_df.to_json(json_output, indent = 1, orient = 'records')
```

Comment: try just `customer_df.to_json(json_output, indent = 1, orient = 'records')`, withtout the `output=`

Answer (score 1):

Which pandas version are you using? Using "indent" keyword requires version >= 1.0.0